# Does referencing a shared pointer in a lambda preserve object lifetime?

Tags: c++

Basically the question from the title. Consider I have to use some asynchronous API, does a reference to the local scope shared ptr in lambda preserve it's lifetime? And is this a safe practice?

```
class A
{
public:
    static void foo();
}

A::foo()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyType> MyTypePtr = std::make_shared<MyType>();
    MyTypePtr->asyncAPI([&MyTypePtr]() // this would return as soon as called
    {
        // doStuffWith MyTypePtr...
    });
}
```

Comment: why do you not capture the shared ptr by value?

Comment: "does a reference to the local scope shared ptr in lambda preserve it's lifetime" - no; "is it safe" - also no, just capture by value.

Comment: Storing a reference to an automatic object for later use is never safe. (And a reference to a `shared_ptr` is almost always pointless.)

Comment: Creating a reference to `shared_ptr` has no effect on the lifetime of pointer or of the managed object.

Comment: You need to capture the shared_ptr by value, that will increase the ref count of the shared pointer and your object's lifetime is extended to that of the lambda.

Comment: btw its odd that you capture `MyTypePtr` to call a method on `MyTypePtr`. It seems like the capture isnt really needed (nor does it prevent `MyTypePtr` from getting destroyed)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it is not odd at all. Clearly the code wants to create the `MyTypePtr` object inside of `foo()` and then use the object at some later time after `foo()` has exited. The callback given to `asyncAPI()` doesn't appear to provide access to the object that `asyncAPI()` was called on. Hence the capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lambda captures the `shared_ptr` ***by reference***. That's what "`&`" means, in the capture list. It only captures a reference to the `shared_ptr`. When the function returns the `shared_ptr` gets destroyed, leaving the lambda holding a bag with a reference to a destroyed object. Any further usage of this object results in undefined behavior.

A lambda capture never preserves the lifetime of anything. It either captures by value, effectively copying the captured object (with the original object's lifetime not affected in any way), or it captures by reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Please don't do so!**

If I understand correctly, the lambda will be executed on another thread. The suggestion still works even if it's not the case.

If you can't promise the lifetime of the `shared_ptr`, pass it by value, and the lifetime of the object will be extended.

`MyTypePtr` will be destroyed once it leaves the scope of `A::foo()`. And the reference in the lambda will be a dangling reference.

Comment: when passing by value, I saw ```Leak_DefinitelyLost``` from valgrind while testing my API, using the reference seemed to solve the issue